# Fragment not added on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation, illegalstateexception, screen-rotation

I'm using a fragment like this:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements MyListener {

    private String name, id;

    public MyFragment(){
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Restoring saved state");
            // Restore id & name
            ....
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);  
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // do stuff with AsyncHttpClient that will call "onResponseReady" after some time
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponseReady() {

        if (!isAdded()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Fragment not added");
            return;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Fragment added");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putString(KEY_ID, this.id);
        outState.putString(KEY_NAME, this.name);
    }
}
```

When i launch the app I get the `Fragment added` message in the LogCat, but if I rotate the device then I get `Fragment not added`, so if I try to access some View (e.g. a TextView defined in `my_fragment.xml`) I get an `IllegalStateException: Fragment MyFragment not attached to Activity`.

Why is the fragment not attached to activity after an orientation change?

Comment: Found the problem: when the device gets rotated then the whole activity is recreated. So the Activity `onCreate` is called, and, in this method, I'm replacing the current fragment with another one. That's why MyFragment is not attached.

Comment: How did you fix this issue?

Comment: I don't remember the solution very well, but I think I modified the activity's onCreate method in order to do the transition only if there was no `savedInstanceState`